# String manipulation in JavaScript array using lodash

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, handlebars.js, lodash

I have a JavaScript array which looks like this:

```
var arr = ["[Dim1].[Mem1].&[1]",
           "[Dim2].[Mem1].&[2]",
           "[Dim1].[Mem1].&[5]",
           "[Dim2].[Mem1].&[77]",
           "[Dim3].[Mem1].&[1]"
          ]
```

**I want output in this format:**

```
{
    [Dim1].[Mem1].&[1], [Dim1].[Mem1].&[5]
},
{
     [Dim2].[Mem1].&[2], [Dim2].[Mem1].&[77]
},
{
     [Dim3].[Mem1].&[1]"]
}
```

The idea is to split each value based on '.&' and then group by the result[0].

I am able to do this by:

1. Loop over all the items in array & then split them with .&
2. Create another list based on [dim].[mem] combination. In our case the list will have [Dim3].[Mem1], [Dim1].[Mem1], [Dim2].[Mem1].
3. Now have two loop - One for every item in unique list and one for every item in original list & check if the item is original list contains the current item in unique list & then form the string.

How can I achieve this using "lodash" or any other JS based library which will reduce the code and make the method compact?

Comment: Have you tried using any other library? Can you share with us what you have tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite literally, actually:

```
_.chain(arr)
.invoke("split", ".&")
.groupBy(0)
.map(function(els) {
    return "{\n\t"+ _.invoke(els, "join", ".&").join(", ") + "\n}";
})
.value().join(",\n");
```